# Adding and opening a PDF file to an Xcode project in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, pdf

I'd like to know how to open a PDF file that's stored in my Xcode project in OS X Preview. It doesn't have to be Preview, just the default program that opens PDFs on the user's computer. I'm making a reading program. I'm working with Swift 2 with Xcode 7 and I'm making an OS X Cocoa application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if let pdfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("pdfFileName", withExtension: "pdf"){
    if NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(pdfURL) {
        print("pdf successfully opened")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That did it!

Comment: Yeah! I wanted to up vote yours but couldn't till now. Thanks again!

Comment: Question, how do I map this into a Topbar Help - I'm trying to make a dropdown menu entry open up a specific PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift 3

```
if let pdfURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"pdfFileName", withExtension: "pdf"){
    if NSWorkspace.shared().open(pdfURL) {
         print("pdf successfully opened")
    }
}
```